# Using the same "Voting" controller action for two different objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am following schneems's great intro to [Rails tutorial](https://github.com/schneems/reddit_on_rails/blob/master/part_two_comments_and_votes.md) on creating a Reddit clone, and want to expand the "voting" structure to work not only for questions, but for comments as well, and was having difficulty figuring out how to pass into the controller both `question_id` and `comment_id` so it could vote up or down accordingly, rather than restricting the usage to only `question_id`.

Currently, there is only a `create` function in my `VotesController`, defined as the following:

```
  def create
    @vote = Vote.where(:question_id => params[:vote][:question_id], :user_id => current_user.id).first #the question_id is baked right in.. 
    if @vote
      @vote.up = params[:vote][:up]
      @vote.save
    else
      @vote = current_user.votes.create(params[:vote])
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you try to vote on a comment, that would mean that `params[:vote]` should contain a `:comment_id` instead of a `:question_id`, right?

So your `where` statement needs to either be

```
# for a question
where(:question_id => params[:vote][:question_id], :user_id => current_user.id)

# for a comment
where(:comment_id => params[:vote][:comment_id], :user_id => current_user.id)
```

You approach this in various ways, like by checking if `params[:vote].has_key?(:question_id)`, but an easy option would be to use [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice):

```
where(params[:vote].slice(:question_id, :comment_id).merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
```

Comment: Thanks, and for posting the `Hash#slice` link! The above code is working great for the first comment posted under a question. However, I wasn't able to vote for any of the subsequent comments posted under the same question, though clicking on the vote links didn't produce any errors. As clarification, each Question `has_many` comments.  Im not sure why its only taking the inputs once, since the each of the comment_ids fed in are unique.. thanks again!

Comment: After digging at this some more, I found out that it was a validation in my `Votes.rb` model thats causing the issue.  I have `validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :question_id }`, which keeps a user from voting for any question more than once.  However, since I render comments in the same `show` page as my questions, I think maybe thats whats causing the issue as users could only vote for one comment that appears under the question, but any of the other ones. Any insights you have would be great, and thanks again.

Comment: Yep, it sounds like a perfect use-case for [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Basically `Vote belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true` and `Question has_many :votes, as: :voteable`.